# Replacement for Win Storage Spaces

Tags: storage

My "big" Windows Server is nearing capacity in terms of physical hard disk slots and I'm thinking about augmenting it with a *nix system as a dedicated file server. CIFS, Active Directory and iSCSI will work with Linux, but I'm using Windows Storage Space with 4TB, 6TB and 8TB HDD drives.

My question is: Is there any way to do this on *nix with a "RAID 0" configuration:

1. Use different disk sizes in a "Pool"
2. Distribute access to the different disks. as good as possible. Server network will be 10G Ethernet thus saturating parallel accesses to several HDD drives

I think the requirements discount anything based on ZFS, BTRFS, LVM and mdadm. Are there any alternatives to that on *nix? I'd really like to save on several 100s of $/€ on a new Windows Servers license. I don't necessarily need a nice GUI, I'm comfortable with bash and vim.

Comment: Why are you discounting ZFS, LVM, etc.? If you're considering this as a file server do you have a plan for handling data loss when a disk dies? (With RAID 0, when you lose a disk you've lost the filesystem.)

Comment: AFAIK, the solutions don't support striping with different sizes of disks? You may be able to concatenate disks, but the you don't get parallel access. Please correct me, if I'm wrong! Also I'm already running this as file server. I'm just looking to replace Win Storage Spaces with a cheaper solution. And it really is "My" (personal) server, so fancy integrity checking is not necessary. Think "Storage, as cheap and fast as possible"